# Joomla 2.5 and Commuinity Polls Error

Tags: php, apache, joomla, joomla2.5

My Joomla 2.5 installation has an extension installed called Community Polls, it is from the corejoomla website. I have a menu item that is a "Community poll home" item. When a user, (me, because the site is not live yet) goes to that menu item(page), a 500 Apache error is returned. digging into the Apache Error logs:

```
[Thu Oct 04 09:11:34 2012] [error] [client 75.150.17.49] Premature end of script headers:   php5.cgi, referer: http://removedforsecurity.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_communitypolls&view=polls
```

Even deeper, on the admin interface, I can look at all the community polls configuration options and they work fine EXCEPT categories, when I click on categories, the 500 error pops up. In the DB the categories table is present and has data in it. Not knowing the design of CP(community polls) I could tell you if the data in categories is corrupting the request.

Any Ideas?

Comment: what PHP and Apache versions are you using?

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is uninstall the component and make sure all of the DB tables associated with it are removed. Then reinstall and reconfigure the component and try again.

Obviously do the basics as well - make sure both Joomla and CP are both the latest versions, make sure that PHP is new enough (you should be ok as long as you are not on PHP version less than 5.2.0).

Comment: I fixed it, it was MSQL problem, more later